How Android App create specific default bearer (MCX - APN) and send sip register over MCX default bearer(QCI 69)
How to incorporate following changes into Android app:

Establish specific APN named 'mcx' with EPS ( we have full control of EPS)

Are we able to check how much default bearer created in my device, through by Android App(if possible provide the specific class like. NetworkInterface, ConnectivityManager etc or device specific)

how to SEND SIP REGISTER message to specific default bearer(i.e. 69 QCI) established between CLIENT_DEVICE and EPS.

Do we need specific requirement from device(HW & OS) manufacturers for the same, if Yes what exactly we need from them.


NOTE:By default SIP register message from android app goes over INTERNET Default Bearer(QCI 9) and in IMS we use Bearer with QCI-5, which almost every device supports.
Assuming: We will configure the SIM as per requirement that will send APN value "mcx" to EPS and establish default bearer(QCI 69) between CLIENT_DEVICE_MOBILE  and EPS .
Then, how Android Application get to know info about this bearer and send next SIP register over this.

Hey @Sandeep, have you had any luck with finding more information about creating MCX apps on Android? This is something I'm looking into as well and there is not much information out there.
